# Windows batch looping through subfolders and running a command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to have a nested for loop in windows command prompt where I go to each subfolder in a specified folder to concatenate all the text files in there into one text file. I'm trying to use

```
FOR /F  IN (.) DO (for %f in (*.dat) do type “%f” >> aggregate.txt)
```

but its not working. Someone help me!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you want to concatenate .txt or .dat files, but this should work for .dat

```
(for /r %f in (*.dat) do @type "%f")>aggregate.txt
```

Type `HELP FOR` from the command line for more info on the many forms of the FOR statement.

It is more efficient to enclose the whole command in parentheses and do redirection just once instead of doing append redirection for each file.

***EDIT*** - *solution for refined requirement in comment: one aggregate per folder*

If needed, first delete any existing aggregate.txt files

```
del /s aggregate.txt
```

Then the following should give you your desired result

```
for /r %F in (*.dat) do @type "%F" >>"%~dpF\aggregate.txt"
```

Note that if you put the commands in a batch file you must double the percents before the FOR variables. For example, `%F` on the command line would need to be `%%F` in a batch file.

Comment: That helps a lot! But I'm trying to concatenate all the .dat files in each subfolder and leave the output .txt file in the subfolders itself. The above code helps me concatenate ALL the .dat files in ALL the subfolders.

Comment: @user1436056 - Added a solution for one aggregate per folder.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `for /r ...` to walk all subdirectories of a given directory. Example:

```
for /r %f in (*.dat) do @type %d >> aggregate.txt
```

no nesting needed. Alternately:

```
(for /r %f in (*.dat) do @type %d) >> aggregate.txt
```

You can use `/d` instead of `/r` to go only one level deep in the hierarchy and list *only folders* (not files matching a certain wildcard). Which could be used as a piece of the puzzle when doing the directory traversal "manually". However, given the issues with variable expansion (inside loops, with and without subs) in NT scripts I would recommend you stick to the straightforward solution. I've used this for cleanup scripts in the past, but moved to `for /r` for some time now.

---

This should get you started

```
@echo off
for /r %%i in (*.dat) do @call :ConcatFolder "%%i"

:ConcatFolder
if "" == "%1" goto :EOF
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set FLDR=%~dp1
type "%1" >> "%FLDR%aggregate.txt"
endlocal & goto :EOF
```

Comment: That helps a lot! But I'm trying to concatenate all the .dat files in each subfolder and leave the output .txt file in the subfolders itself. The above code helps me concatenate ALL the .dat files in ALL the subfolders.

Comment: Okay, so per-folder all files (e.g. `.dat`) into a single `.txt` file, correct? I'll adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: yeap! Thank you so much! Is there anyway of putting all those different subfolder aggregate data into different excel sheets?

Comment: @user1436056: no idea, sorry. My take on this would be via comma-separated files, but I haven't use any Excel even on other people's computers in ages.